# Single sign on integration with angular app gives a CORS error on redirecting the SAML request

Tags: python, cors, single-sign-on, saml-2.0, onelogin

I'm trying to integrate my company's SSO to the web app I've developed. I'm using **Angular** in the frontend and **Django** as the backend.

In order to create the SAML request, I'm using OneLogin's **[python-saml](https://github.com/onelogin/python-saml)**. The flow for SSO is:

- The user sends a login request to the backend
- Backend creates redirected SAML request as a response
- Frontend redirects to SSO page(user has to select the entity he/she belongs to)
- SSO authenticates the user and sends a response to the backend

I'm able to create the SAML request but when the browser redirects to the SSO page, I get a CORS error:

> `Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: “No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource”`

But when I copy the SAML request from the **Location** header and open in the new tab, the SSO page loads, and I am able to select the entity.

I've looked at other apps which already have SSO integrated and I've found out the following differences in the SAML request headers (**header : my app vs other app**):

- **Origin** : **null** vs No **Origin** present
- **sec-fetch-mode** : **cors** vs **navigate**
- **sec-fetch-dest** : **empty** vs **document**

I'm not able to find a way to configure these headers in the OneLogin's library, so I'm not sure if these headers are the reason why I'm getting the cors error.

If I am missing out on something, kindly let me know. Help me understand why I am getting the error.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: any news on this?